# Feature extraction with TSFEL giving inconsistent sizes

Tags: time-series, classification, feature-selection, importance

Looks like this is [TSFEL's](https://tsfel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) first appearance on Stack Overflow.

> Time Series Feature Extraction Library (TSFEL for short) is a Python
> package for feature extraction on time series data.

Here goes. I'm following [this example](https://github.com/fraunhoferportugal/tsfel/blob/master/notebooks/TSFEL_HAR_Example.ipynb). I input my data into [time_series_features_extractor](https://tsfel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/descriptions/modules/tsfel.feature_extraction.html?highlight=time_series_features_extractor#tsfel.feature_extraction.calc_features.time_series_features_extractor) where X and y have respectively shapes `(5244, 19) (5244,)`. The output gives me an X_train of shape `(1, 7410)` which I cannot input into any classifier because my y_train is still `(5244,)`.

The example does this without blinking in the *Feature Extraction* segment, so there is something I'm misunderstanding.

If there is anyone here that has experience with TSFEL or other Time Series Feature extractors, any tips or help is well thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the shape (5244,19) corresponds to 5244 windows with dimension 19 right?
If that so, I think that for solving your problem you should expand your X with one more dimension obtaining a shape of (5244, 19, 1) meaning (windows, window_size, number_of_sensors).

TSFEL is flexible enough to extract features from multiple sensors at the time, and if you
don't specify that you are only using one sensor it assumes that you have only one window with 5244 size and 19 sensors.

This example is available on Colab you can try it in here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/fraunhoferportugal/tsfel/blob/master/notebooks/TSFEL_HAR_Example.ipynb

Hope this helps.